# How to use nativescript-orientation plugin in typescript & Angular 2 in nativescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm going to use nativescript-orientation plugin in my project.
https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-orientation#argslandscape--true--false

I want to change all layout when orientation changes automatically.
So I'm going to use this function.

```
exports.orientation(args)
args.landscape = true | false
args.page (depreciated) or args.object = the current page
```

But I don't know how to insert it in my typescript & angluar 2 project.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
    var Orientation = require( "nativescript-orientation" );
    @Component({
        selector: "my-app",
        templateUrl: "app.component.html",
    })
     export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
        public counter: number = 16;
         public get message(): string {
            if (this.counter > 0) {
                return this.counter + " taps left";
            } else {
                return "Hoorraaay! \nYou are ready to start building!";
            }
        }
        ngOnInit(){
            console.log(Orientation.getOrientation()+"--phone"); 
        }
        public onTap() {
            this.counter--;
        }
   }

export function orientation(args){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the CSS rules for your landscape/portrait modes and you are good to go.

r.g.
***app.css***

```
.btn {
    font-size: 18;
}

.landscape Button {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

.landscape StackLayout {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

***app.component.ts***

```
import { Component} from "@angular/core";
var orientation = require('nativescript-orientation');

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent {

    public onTap() {
        console.log(orientation.getOrientation());  
    }
}
```

***app.component.html***

```
<StackLayout class="p-20">
    <Label text="Tap the button" class="h1 text-center"></Label>
    <Button text="TAP" (tap)="onTap()" class="btn btn-primary btn-active"></Button>
    <Button text="Sample Button"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

Full working demo [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/tree/master/stackoverflow/orienationPlugin) (once the app loads manually rotate the screen)

Comment: I want to change layout as well as style when change landscape and portrait eachother

Comment: you can't change layouts runtime with this plugin.. in fact you can't change layouts runtime in NativeScript. However, you can simply show/hide layouts depending on a boolean variable which you can set according to the orientation value.  Also if you want to load layouts depending on the orientation BUILD time then you can use screen qualifiers pages https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/supporting-multiple-screens#screen-size-qualifiers